# Pandas dataframe to_sql with data longer than 65536 characters

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe, where some columns have values longer than 65536 characters. When I tried to export the data to MySQL using `df.to_sql(con=engine, name=table_name, if_exists='replace', index=False)`, they were truncated to 65536 characters.

Is there a way to automatically convert a column to LONGTEXT or BLOB (instead of TEXT) if it has values longer than 65536 so that the table content won't be truncated?

Answer (score 2):

This might be a workaround. The only thing is you need to have the list of columns that need to be converted to LONGTEXT.

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import LONGTEXT
dtype = {
    "long_column_1": LONGTEXT,
    "long_column_2": LONGTEXT
}
pdf.to_sql(con=engine, name=table_name, if_exists='replace', index=False, dtype=dtype)
```